# How can I show these ListView items without the images being clipped?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a `ListView` that contains a `CheckBox` and an `ImageButton`. So far, I have the following working, which is depicted below:

[image]

This is the layout of each ListView item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/datetime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rbOutput"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/rbOutput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[User Output]"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the image has the top and bottom clipped off. How can I show the full image and the `checkbox` to the left of it, vertically centered in each `ListView` item?

For reference, this is the complete unclipped image:

[image]

Comment: put your relativelayout height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

to the xml definition for the image to Scale the image using CENTER

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use several options of `scaleType` for `ImageView`; here are the options and outputs of them respectively.

http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html